# Why is the water from Siruvani dam called 'Worlds 2nd tastiest water'?

Tags: india, kerala

Siruvani is one of the remote tourist locations in Kerala, India.

I have visited Siruvani reservoir as it is quite near to my home. And **it is said that the water from siruvani is the worlds 2nd tastiest**.

How could we measure the taste of water? Is it based on cleanliness, or something else?

Then which water body has the most tastiest water in the world?

Comment: "Tastiest" is a purely opinionated value, there really is no standard that can be applied, as what you think tastes good and what I think are different.

Comment: But this can be found on the web, googling "world's second tastiest water"

Comment: Change your search to simply "worlds tastiest water" and you get all sorts of claims.  But again they are all opinions and I imagine the person that coined the phrase has not tasted ALL of the natural water sources in the world.

Comment: @AbhishekK If something is found on the web doesn't make it true or a fact. Maybe someone did a 'taste test' drinking 20 waters and chose the siruvani water. There's no official standard so anyone could claim to have the tastiest water. It's like you claiming you bake the tastiest apple pie, you can.

Comment: Why is it called that? Because they want people to visit the dam.

Comment: Vote to reopen. Unless it gets closed for some other reasons, I don't get how a question on the origin of the name given to a touristic place can be opinion based, and this has even a proper objective answer. Or are we going to close the next question asking why the leaning tower of Pisa is called "leaning" ???

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sweetest-water-in-the-world), where someone has explained:

> The Guinness Book of World Record for the 'Sweetest Tasting Water in the World' goes to Tomalistis Falls in the Caibiran municipality of Biliran, Philippines. You can read more about it here - [Taste the sweetest water at Tomalistis Falls](https://www.vigattintourism.com/index.php?/tourism/articles/Taste-the-sweetest-water-at-Tomalistis-Falls)

But, note that I wasn't able to find a reference from Guinness itself.

Answer (score 1):

What I found after a long search. (Thank you for your valuable comments).

Softness/Sweetness of water is based upon the mineral content in it. Lesser the salt and mineral content in the water, sweeter/softer the water is. Commonly, water bodies close to a water fall have sweet water because deposition of soil in such water bodies is the least.

As we all know, no one can practically measure the taste of water from all the water bodies on earth, and compare them.

Now, although Siruvani reservoir is widely claimed to have the second sweetest water in the world. But I was not able to find any official source for this claim. And the Guinness Book of World Record for the 'Sweetest Tasting Water in the World' goes to [Tomalistis Falls](https://www.vigattintourism.com/index.php?/tourism/articles/Taste-the-sweetest-water-at-Tomalistis-Falls) in the Caibiran municipality of Biliran, Philippines.

Thanks to Quora :)

Comment: It is interesting that everyone involved in the Quora page that you reference is from India.  Perhaps a little national pride / prejudice in their explanations to keep it ranked number two?